# Is there any maven like tool available for Ionic projects?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, github, ionic-framework

I'm having an Ionic project which I need to keep in github. When you start an Ionic project it auto generates a lot of library files. Do I need to keep all those library files while pushing the project to the github repo ? Is there something similar to maven available for Ionic projects which I can make use of ?

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript projects, we tend to use `npm` or `bower`. `npm` is the main one used these days (certainly has the largest ecosystem) and is also the one I mainly use, but `bower` certainly has quite a few front-end orientated modules that you can use.

`npm` comes packaged with NodeJS automatically; `bower` will require NodeJS to function as well, but is installed separately.

Comment: You could add `gulp/grunt/broccoli` to it as well because Maven also has the ability to compile packages etc.

Comment: `npm` has the ability to do this via shell scripts; there's no need to reach out to those, but yes, they do exist.